# Finding points within distance of polygon using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, proximity

I have several polygons(areas) and points(with names of places) on two different layers.

How would I go about finding all of the points that reside within 100m of the polygons I have on the other layer?

So far I have created the 100m buffer around the polygons and I can visually see that there are quite a few overlaps. How would I go about extracting the names from the points that are covered by the polygons?

- Or is there another way I should go about doing this? (***eg. a query***)
- Then how would I go about classifying the distance of these newly found areas? eg, into steps of 20m, so 0m-20m,20m-40m,40m-60m etc.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question per question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [Select by Location](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//00s50000002q000000) tool (menu > Selection > Select by Location).

[image]

1. set the *target layer*, the layer from which the selection to be
   made (for example, the point feature)
2. set the *source layer* (polygon)
3. select *are within a distance of the source layer feature* from the *Spatial selection method* drop down
4. set the search distance (100) and unit (meter)
5. click apply

To extract only the names you can export the selected points to a new feature (Table of content > right click on layer > Data > Export data). My style is to add a new text field to the point *attribute table* and copy the selected layer names to the new field. You can even use this method for making ranges of distance, both in *attribute table* and *symbology*.

Answer (score 1):

To find the points use the [Select layer by location tool](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000072000000).

For the distances I don't really understand what you want, so please explain a little bit and then I'll update my answer.

Comment: I found what I was looking for, the near tool in proximity in the analysist toolbox was also good for what I was doing.